# Are all incoming requests handled by AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC 5 website which uses local STS for authentication.
I subclassed the AuthorizeAttribute to customize authentication/authorization process, added MyAuthorizeAttribute to GlobalFilters.
When user came in without authenticated, MyAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorize successfully caught it and create a SignInRequest to redirect to STS. That is what I want.
I observed that when user authenticated successfully and STS redirected user back, user's browser POSTed a SAML token embedded in request body to my MVC web application, this is by design, and I expected MyAuthenticateAttribute could catch this request, so I can extract the token from request body, check and validate it, however, MyAuthenticateAttribute.OnAuthorize() function didn't get called this time, it directly went to controller. 
So is there anything wrong? Where should i catch and handle the token POSTed from user? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to decorate your action method with [Authorize] attribute or if you want authorization to happen for all actions in a controller, then set that attribute on the controller itself.

Also take a look at the usage of [AllowAnonymous] at  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008731/Insight-of-ASP-NET-MVC-s-Authorize-Attribute

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have added MyAuthorizeAttribute to GlobalFilters.

Answer (score 1):

`AuthorizeAttribute` is both an `Attribute` and a `IAuthorizationFilter`. `Attributes` don't actually *do* anything, the MVC framework scans for where this attribute is added and registers it as a filter on the fly.

However, rather than decorating controllers or action methods with it, you could add it as a global filter:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizationAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

By the same token, you can create your own `IAuthorizationFilter` or subclass `AuthorizeAttribute` to do whatever you want. If registered globally, it will always run for all actions and then you can use it to do custom authorization of requests globally.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have added MyAuthorizeAttribute to GlobalFilters.